# how to convert time from timestamp to readable time in bokeh hover?

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I need to convert the time on bokeh hover tool. it show me unix timestamp instead of readable one.

**Code:**

```
up = df["up"]
ttime = time["timetable"]
time = pandas.to_datetime(time, unit='s')
p.line(time, up, color='#2828B0', line_width=1, legend='Up')


hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Time', '@x'),
                         ('Value', '@y GB')])
```

[image: Check The Time!!]

Comment: Try using `hover.formatters = { "Date": "datetime"}`

Comment: This is the correct answer, if you make a real answer I will happily vote it up.